# Есть ли здесь в обороте с союзом "как" значение причинности и нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как произведения искусства (,) они стали инновационной заготовкой для искусствоведов и философов, увидевших в них новое направление для художественно-эстетического и философского осмысления проблемы «научного искусства».

Comment: А о чем речь? Без понимания смысла (они - это кто?) сложно разобраться с наличием или отсутствием значения причинности для данного оборота.

Comment: В тонких металлических пленках наноразмерной толщины, получаемых при нанесении покрытий на водорастворимую основу, художник увидел произведения искусства. Получается действительно красиво, даже не верится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае сравнительный оборот можно заменить оборотом с будучи. В этом случае запятая ставится.

Comment: Спасибо большое!